# Accessing Meteor Settings in a Self-Owned Production Environment

Tags: settings, meteor, production-environment

According to Meteor's [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settings), we can include a settings file through the command line to provide deployment-specific settings.

However, the `--settings` option seems to only be available through the `run` and `deploy` commands. If I am running my Meteor application on my own infrastructure - as outlined in the *Running on Your Own Infrastructure* section of the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying) - there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a deployment-specific settings file anywhere in the process.

**Is there a way to access Meteor settings in a production environment, running on my own infrastructure?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, include the settings contents in an environmental variable `METEOR_SETTINGS`.  For example,

`export METEOR_SETTINGS='{"privateKey":"MY_KEY", "public":{"publicKey":"MY_PUBLIC_KEY", "anotherPublicKey":"MORE_KEY"}}'`

And then run the meteor app as normal.

This will populate the Meteor.settings object has normal.  For the settings above,

```
Meteor.settings.privateKey == "MY_KEY" #Only on server
Meteor.settings.public.publicKey == "MY_PUBLIC_KEY" #Server and client
Meteor.settings.public.anotherPublicKey == "MORE_KEY" #Server and client
```

For our [project](http://madeye.io), we use an [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script and include it there (although upstart has a slightly different syntax).  However, if you are starting it with a normal shell script, you just need to include that `export` statement before your node command.  You could, for example, have a script like:

```
export METEOR_SETTINGS='{"stuff":"real"}'
node /path/to/bundle/main.js
```

or

`METEOR_SETTINGS='{"stuff":"real"}' node /path/to/bundle/main.js`

You can find more information about bash variables [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html).

Comment: So, in the code `Meteor.settings.privateKey` will work as expected?

Comment: Awesome. So, I'm guessing the export statement is in your code? Is there a particular location in the codebase that you put that statement?

Comment: Yeah, put it in whatever init script you are using to start the meteor process, or prefix the start command with it.  I've edited to answer to explain that a bit more.

Comment: Appreciate the explanations.

Comment: Will the above exclude MONGO_URL, ROOT_URL? I've tried the above and get this - "Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment". I exported, sourced a bash file with it, ran it on command line, nothing seems to work until I explicity define export MONGO_URL=...