# Meteor settings on windows

Tags: json, windows, meteor, environment-variables

I am developing and testing meteor application on Windows 7.

I have meteor settings

```
{
  "public": {
    "runMode": "SERVER"
  }
}
```

That I keep in **METEOR_SETTINGS** environment variable.

When the application is started in production mode

```
meteor --production
```

The console.log result of whole Meteor.settings object looks like this:

```
{
  "public": {}
}
```

There is nothing but empty public property.

When I run mu meteor project in development mode

```
meteor
```

The console.log result of whole Meteor.settings object looks like this:

```
{
  "public": {
    "runMode": "SERVER"
  }
}
```

So, it works fine in development mode.

But I am unable to have any settings in production mode.

Can you please advise on this.

PS

This problem is not present in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is present only when Meteor application is started in production mode with `meteor --production`

Once meteor is builded into nodejs code everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean that using meteor --settings settings.json, you were able to access that public variable "runMode"? If so, you are doing it correctly. Meteor does not know to use the settings.json automatically. You have attach the settings.json file and when the meteor server loads, it gets all the variables from that file.

Comment: I am having the problem with case when I do not set --settings settings.json. Then Metero should get the settings from METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable. Correct? What is correct way of using settings when meteor app is builded in a bundle, and started as node app? Thanks.

Comment: I guess this link might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090281/accessing-meteor-settings-in-a-self-owned-production-environment

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful, but that is not my real problem. My problem is that the public is always empty when running on windows.